# Explicit locking variables in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a test variable `User::TEST` that is chose in the `ReadOnlyVariable` list.

From the script, I explicitly locking the variable and read it. The code works fine. But why the script did not fail? It is suppose to fail because I explicitly lock the same variable 2nd time as it (from either `ReadOnly` or `ReadWrite` list) would be locked during the `execute phase`, isn't it?

sample locking code:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        try
        {
            Variables variable = null;
            string A;

            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::TEST");

            Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref variable);

            A = variable["User::TEST"].Value.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(A);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that should make it fail?   Did you read it somewhere?   If so, can  you post the link?

Comment: @TabAlleman, yes, here is the link http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/A-deadlock-was-detected-while-trying-to-lock-variables-in-SSIS.aspx, please refer to the last sentence: `Update...`